# Using Mocha with synchronizedjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to use synchronizedjs in my testcaes, but now any test passes.

```
test.it("Clicking previous week button, causes loading previous week",()=>{
        sync.fiber(()=>{
            var currentMondayText = sync.await(driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className("date"))).getText();
            assert.equal(true,false);
        });
});
```

So can somebody tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any tests with callbacks break the simple function return handling that Mocha typically relies on. To solve this, you can ask for a `done` parameter in your test function and call that when the test has completed:

```
test.it("Clicking previous week button, causes loading previous week", (done) => {
  sync.fiber(() => {
    var currentMondayText = sync.await(driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className("date"))).getText();
    assert.equal(true,false);
    done();
  });
});
```

When your test function takes this parameter, Mocha will not finish the test until it has been called.

If your test uses a thenable matching the promises standard, you can also return that from the test and Mocha will notice and wait for it to resolve:

```
test.it('returns a promise', () => {
  return foo.promise().then(result => {
    expect(result).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Using done, causes the test to not finish, till timeout is reached

Comment: Exactly like you mentioned in your answer

Comment: Are you sure your test code is reaching the call to done?